# NSMutable array error & showAnnotations

Tags: objective-c, arrays, annotations, mutable

I have the following situation. I developed an app that frequently retrieves values for POI's that I want to show as annotations on a map. For this I wrote the method below, called after when a new set of POIs was retrieved:

```
-(void)showAnnotation{

[self removeAllPinsButUserLocation];

annotationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (Poi *poi in [parser.pois allValues]) {

    myAnnotation *arr = [[myAnnotation alloc] init];
    arr.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%@)",poi.description, sensor.name];
    arr.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@",poi.street, poi.postalcode, poi.city];
    arr.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(poi.lattitude, poi.longitude);

    [annotationArray addObject:arr];

    arr = nil;
}

[self.mapView addAnnotations:annotationArray];
[self.mapView showAnnotations:annotationArray animated:NO];
```

}

Problem is that I get an error (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x14ebe9b0> was mutated while being enumerated.')

However only if I set animated:NO in the last line, but not when set to animated:YES...

Does anyone have an answer for this?

Thanks for replying!

Eelco

Comment: Where is this method called from?  Are you sure `parser.pois` isn't being retrieved (modified) _while_ this method is looping through the values?  Does the app retrieve POIs on a timer or through some user action?

Comment: @Anna: in a XMLParser object, in the parserDidEndDocument method I call the showAnnotation method. So in my opinion this shouldn't be possible. Also, in the iOS Simulator no error occurs, only on my iPhone...

Comment: Execution on the real device is probably a bit slower, it may have a different iOS version, etc. which could all result in exposing a problem in the code where it relies on specific things happening in a specific order in some specific time period.  Perhaps your parsing is getting initiated again while showAnnotation is still running.  You'll have to do some debugging with the real device using NSLogs, breakpoints.  Maybe parserDidEndDocument is too low-level a method from which to know that it's ok to start this "time consuming" process of showing annotations.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts! I thought the same thing, so I already started re-coding some methods and will use the notification center to start showing annotations after the parsing has finished. I hope that this will work better on the device itself.